# Hide an object in a linked group

Tags: rendering, linked-data, groups

I have a character made of several objects that I am linking into a scene. The character's objects are part of a group, and I'm linking in the group. However, for certain scenes I want to hide some of the objects inside the group (articles of clothing the character is wearing.) Is there a way to do this?

I am familiar with the proxy system. It allows me to create a proxy of an object, but even if I set the proxy to be hidden, it still shows. If I move the proxied object somewhere off camera that seems to work. Using mask modifier on it doesn't work either. The proxy itself does get hidden, but then it still shows a version from the group.

It seems I can start with the items hidden and then proxy the ones I want to show, but that quickly defeats the point of linking. Any other options?

Comment: Only workaround I see is using group isntances inside the main character group instance. Include said artivles as group instances in the Character group, then you can use the *Outliner* in [Group Mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68476/what-is-the-best-way-to-overcome-layers-limitation-in-blender) and turn off visibility/renderability of individual groups on a per-scene basis.